# Implementing code from walkdir's documentation

Tags: rust

I am new to rust and trying to figure out what I am doing wrong here. From the [docs.rs page on `walkdir`](https://docs.rs/walkdir/2.3.1/walkdir/):

> The following code recursively iterates over the directory given and prints the path for each entry:
>
> ```
> use walkdir::WalkDir;
>
> for entry in WalkDir::new("foo") {
>     println!("{}", entry?.path().display());
> }
> ```

However when I try to run this as a simple program:

```
use walkdir::WalkDir;
fn main() {
    for entry in WalkDir::new("~/Documents/ExampleDir/") {
        println!("{}", entry?.path().display());
    }
}
```

I get a compilation error:

```
error[E0277]: the `?` operator can only be used in a function that returns `Result` or `Option` (or another type that implements `Try`)
 --> src/main.rs:4:24
  |
2 | / fn main() {
3 | |     for entry in WalkDir::new("foo") {
4 | |         println!("{}", entry?.path().display());
  | |                        ^^^^^^ cannot use the `?` operator in a function that returns `()`
5 | |     }
6 | | }
  | |_- this function should return `Result` or `Option` to accept `?`
  |
  = help: the trait `Try` is not implemented for `()`
  = note: required by `from_error`
```

If I remove the `?` operator then I get a different compilation error:

```
error[E0599]: no method named `path` found for enum `std::result::Result<walkdir::DirEntry, walkdir::Error>` in the current scope
 --> src/main.rs:4:30
  |
4 |         println!("{}", entry.path().display());
  |                              ^^^^ method not found in `std::result::Result<walkdir::DirEntry, walkdir::Error>`
```

What am I doing wrong here? Is this an issue in my code or in the documentation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `?` is shorthand for a match statement. See [The question mark operator](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/expressions/operator-expr.html#the-question-mark-operator).

> The question mark operator (?) unwraps valid values or returns erroneous values, propagating them to the calling function. It is a unary postfix operator that can only be applied to the types Result<T, E> and Option.

The (`main`) function requires a return value of type [`Result`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/result/):

```rust
use std::error::Error;
use walkdir::WalkDir;

fn main() -> Result<(), Box<dyn Error>> {
    for entry in WalkDir::new("~/Documents/ExampleDir/") {
        println!("{}", entry?.path().display());
    }
    Ok(())
}
```

Comment: Also ~ will not expand to the home directory, this is something the shell does. @Isaac: You might want to use the [`home_dir` function in the `dirs` crate](https://docs.rs/dirs/3.0.1/dirs/fn.home_dir.html).

Comment: Thank you this makes sense. @HHK I will look into that.

Comment: I was writing a post with the same question. I'm new to Rust, and there are things I like about it, but the Result/Ok/? syntax is so convoluted that it almost seems intentionally obfuscated. For example, in my case why does main() have to return any Result? And why does the compiler complain about the ? on entry when really the error has nothing to do with that but has to do with the main() return type?